# Eliminating Duplicate Data in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

am using SQL Server 2012, I have a table named Employee, I am trying to get result like

```
SrNo  | Name_of_Employee   |    Known_Technology    |   No_of_Times   
------+--------------------+------------------------+-----------------
    1 |  Mahesh Kumar      |        C#.net          |       2
      |                    |        SQL Server      |       3
      |                    |        ASP.NET         |       1
    2 |  John Dias         |        JAVA            |       2
      |                    |        VB.NET          |       1
      |                    |        Jquery          |       2
    3 |  Sijo Paul         |        Style Sheet     |       1
      |                    |        MySQL           |       2
    4 |  Nichol Sami       |        ASP.NET         |       3
      |                    |        JAVA            |       2
      |                    |        VB.NET          |       1
```

but i am getting like this

```
SrNo  | Name_of_Employee   |    Known_Technology    |   No_of_Times   
------+--------------------+------------------------+-----------------
    1 |  Mahesh Kumar      |        C#.net          |       2
    1 |  Mahesh Kumar      |        SQL Server      |       3
    1 |  Mahesh Kumar      |        ASP.NET         |       1
    2 |  John Dias         |        JAVA            |       2
    2 |  John Dias         |        VB.NET          |       1
    2 |  John Dias         |        Jquery          |       2
    3 |  Sijo Paul         |        Style Sheet     |       1
    3 |  Sijo Paul         |        MySQL           |       2
    4 |  Nichol Sami       |        ASP.NET         |       3
    4 |  Nichol Sami       |        JAVA            |       2
    4 |  Nichol Sami       |        VB.NET          |       1
```

How can I get the desired result..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I totally agree with @Tim Rogers and what i have given is a way around.

```
declare @a as table (SrNo int, Name_of_Employee varchar(50), Known_Technology varchar(50), No_of_Times int)
insert into @a values 
(1, 'Mahesh Kumar','C#.net',2),
(1, 'Mahesh Kumar','SQL Server',3),
(1, 'Mahesh Kumar','ASP.NET',1),
(2, 'John Dias','JAVA',2),
(2, 'John Dias','VB.NET',1),
(2, 'John Dias','Jquery',2),
(3, 'Sijo Paul','Style Sheet',1),
(3, 'Sijo Paul','MySQL',2),
(4, 'Nichol Sami','ASP.NET',3),
(4, 'Nichol Sami','JAVA',2),
(4, 'Nichol Sami','VB.NET',1)

;with cte as(
select row_number() over (partition by Name_of_Employee order by SrNo) as id1,
SrNo, Name_of_Employee,Known_Technology,No_of_Times from @a )

select Name = case id1 when 1 then Name_of_Employee else '' end, 
Known_Technology, No_of_Times from cte
```

Answer (score 6):

That is how grouping and joining work. Don't attempt to use a SQL query to format your data for displaying to the end user - that is what your user interface is for. A SQL query returns *data* - it's up to your UI code to format that for your users.

Answer (score 1):

even though i think this is bad practice:

```
with prep as (
   select srno  
        , name_of_employee
        , known_technology
        , no_of_times
        , row_number() over (partition by srno, name_of_emplyee order by known_technology, no_of_times) as c
    from your_table
)
select case when c = 1 then srno else null end as srno
     , case when c = 1 then name_of_employee else null end name_of_employee
     , known_technology
     , no_of_times
from prep
```

Comment: All Answers are correct.. and appreciable.. I respect to all of u.. Thanks @Brett Schneider, Saad Surya, tehvan and Tim Rogers

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure where you're getting at (Tim Rogers is right about not using SQL for formatting purposes), but it seems you actually need two tables to ensure data integrity:

Employee, which contains information about the employee him/herself
columns:

- SrNo
- Name_Of_Employee

Know_Technologies, which contains information about the known technologies for each employee
columns:

- Employee_SrNo (foreign key to Employee.SrNo)
- Technology_Name
  No_Of_Times

You would have a 1-n relation between Employee and Known_Technology tables.